# How many times should I repeat k-means on particular data?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have implemented my own version of k-means and k-means++ in Python. It works well on some data but sometimes it is stuck at local minimum and gives a bad result.

However, if I repeat k-means several times and pick the result which gives the lowest sum of squared distances between data points and nearest centroids, it works fine and gives me the expected result. I wonder if there is some recommended number of how many times k-means should be run on data, or is it just an experimental issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) testing on multiple (more is better) data, with changing the number of k-means repetition. Than compare the error function with number of repetition. On a great number of data you should be able to decide, how many repetition is enough to reach wanted accuracy of k-means.

Comment: +1 Just to add to this a bit: Cross-validation will split up your data into smaller pieces, train the model on some of the pieces, and test it on others. This will allow you to minimize the error, but it will also prevent it from overfitting—being too dependent on—the training data. You can also try different $k$ or other hyper-parameters to see what works best. Even though you have created your own version of k-means in Python, you can implement it in a standard scikit-learn cross-validation pipeline: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator